# Archivo no encontrado Python 3 lectura "rb"

Tags: funciones, archivo, csv, python-3.7, machine-learning

```
filename = '/home/user/Escritorio/learning_ia/data_preprocessing/algorithms_machinelearning/data_banknote_authentication.csv'
```

pero al llamarlo con una funcion

```
def load_csv(filename):
file = open(filename,'rb')
lines = reader(file)
dataset = list(lines)
return dataset
```

Y ejecutar el codigo me sale el siguiente error 
que esta estoy haciendo mal... ?

```
File "/home/rdymonxd/Escritorio/learning_ia/data_preprocessing/algorithms_machinelearning/3deccsion_tree2.py", line 10, in load_csv
file = open(filename,'rb')FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data_banknote_authentication.csv'
```

Comment: podrias colocar la llamada a la funcion para ver que parametros le estas pasando!

Comment: La ruta que le pasas como parámetro está mal y no encuentra el archivo. Pero sin más detalles no podemos saber porqué.